# With Python and Cinemagoer / imdbpy, the awards is always empty

Tags: python, imdbpy

New to Cinemagoer / imdbpy and trying how it works but the 'awards' is always None and/or empty.
Did I missed something?

0034583 = Casablanca

Regards

```
from imdb import Cinemagoer
ia = Cinemagoer()
movie = ia.get_movie(34583, info=['main', 'awards'])
print(f"movie['title']: {movie['title']}, movie.get('awards'): {movie.get('awards')}, ia.get_movie_awards(movie.movieID): {ia.get_movie_awards(movie.movieID)}")

>>> result:
movie['title']: Casablanca, movie.get('awards'): None, ia.get_movie_awards(movie.movieID): {'data': {}, 'titlesRefs': {}, 'namesRefs': {}}
```

The result is : Won 3 Oscars 14 wins & 10 nominations total
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034583/awards

Comment: `Cinemagoer` is broken. You aren't doing anything wrong. You can use [`PyMovieDb`](https://github.com/itsmehemant7/PyMovieDb) but it does not gather award information. There is also [`imdby`](https://pypi.org/project/imdby/) which also does not support awards.

Comment: `PyMovieDb` seems to return data as JSON. I didn't go deep in the docs to see if there are convenience methods but, if not, you will need to use `json.loads(results)` to turn the return results into something you can actually do something with.

Comment: @OysterShucker PyMovieDb returns a json but not awards entry...

Comment: That's what I said. " You can use PyMovieDb but it does not gather award information" I did almost 1/2 hour of research for you. Nothing returns awards.